# Non-integrability of random variable question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Awhile ago I saw a post "Jumps and slow convergence of empirical mean" (unfortunately, I am unable to find site or author and googling is not helping either) and printed the proof to go through it later to check.

There is a part of the proof I don't quite understand.

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of iid integrable random variable. Suppose $\mathbb{E}\left[|X_1|^{1/(1-\epsilon)}\right] = \infty$ for every $ 0 < \epsilon < 1$. By the non-integrability of $|X_n|^{1/(1-\epsilon)}$, we have 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\left(|X_n| \ge n^{1-\epsilon}/2\right)=\infty.$$

I don't get how non-integrability could led to the result. And I am not sure where the author got term $n^{1-\epsilon}/2$ from. Did the author used some of sort of common knowledge results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows (nearly) directly from $\mathbb{E}|X| = \int_0^\infty P(|X| > t) dt$. (This is somewhat common knowledge that follows from Fubini's theorem (the ability to change the order of integration)).

Since $P(|X|>t)$ is a monotonically decreasing function in $t$, that integral is upper bounded by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|X|>n)$, so if $|X|$ is not integrable, then that sum is also infinite. If you rewrite for $|X|^{1 / 1 - \epsilon}$, it should work out.

I do not know why the author divided the expression by 2, though of course, that sum is lower bounded by the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|X|>n^{1 - \epsilon})$, so if this one is infinite, then so is the other one.